# What is wrong with this NodeJS request that I've converted from CURL?

Tags: node.js, curl

I have a CURL request that gives me the results that I need:

`curl "http://www.domain.com/verification/" --data "ID=123456789&DL=123456789&submit=submit"`

However when I turn it into a NodeJS request like this:

```
var request = require('request');

var dataString = 'ID=123456789&DL=123456789&submit=submit';

var options = {
    url: 'http://www.domain.com/verification/',
    method: 'POST',
    data: dataString
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body);
    }
}

request(options, callback);
```

It gives me back a different response... what is wrong with this?

Comment: What response does it give you?

Comment: When I look in the [doc for `request()`](https://github.com/request/request), I can't find any option named `data:`.  Are you sure that is right?

Comment: you should use like: 
`curl --data "param1=value1&param2=value2" http://hostname/resource`

Comment: The response I get is the body, but it's not the same body that I get when I run the curl request from the command line. When I do the curl request from the command line, it acts as if I'm posting the data to the form on the screen, but when I do it from the request, it acts as though I haven't posted any data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
request.post({
   url:'http://www.domain.com/verification/', 
   form: {
    ID: '123456789',
    DL: '123456789',
    submit: 'submit'
   }
  },
 function(error,response,body){ 
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body);
  }
 });
```

Comment: I am glad I could help

Answer (score -2):

Try this-

```
var request = require('request');
var options = {
    url: 'http://www.domain.com/verification/',
    method: 'POST',
    form: { "ID":"123456789","DL":"123456789","submit":"submit"}
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body);
    }
}

request(options, callback);
```

Comment: hw was trying to send a form, here is the doc clarifying that: https://github.com/request/request